# Errors For Background Script

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

My goal is to debug an IPN or any script that runs out off page. Normally errors can be easily handled, but when they are in the background it's tough to do. The script itself is set off when a user pays at paypal. I can't debug on that page.

How would you log an error off page when it is run when you leave your site as this paypal example.
What I've treid so far..

I've added

`ini_set('log_errors', true);
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__).'/ipn_errors.log');`

with a file called ipn_errors.log within the same folder as the page i'm trying to debug.

```
<?php
// Check to see there are posted variables coming into the script
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != "POST") die ("No Post Variables");
// Initialize the $req variable and add CMD key value pair
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
// Read the post from PayPal
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// Now Post all of that back to PayPal's server using curl, and validate everything with PayPal
// We will use CURL instead of PHP for this for a more universally operable script (fsockopen has issues on some environments)
//$url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
$url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
$curl_result=$curl_err='';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Content-Length: " . strlen($req)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER , 0);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
$curl_result = @curl_exec($ch);
$curl_err = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$req = str_replace("&", "\n", $req);  // Make it a nice list in case we want to email it to ourselves for reporting

// Check that the result verifies
if (strpos($curl_result, "VERIFIED") !== false) {
    $req .= "\n\nPaypal Verified OK";
} else {
    $req .= "\n\nData NOT verified from Paypal!";
    mail("chris@test.com", "IPN interaction not verified", "$req", "From: chris@test.com" );
    exit();
}

/* CHECK THESE 4 THINGS BEFORE PROCESSING THE TRANSACTION, HANDLE THEM AS YOU WISH
1. Make sure that business email returned is your business email
2. Make sure that the transaction’s payment status is “completed”
3. Make sure there are no duplicate txn_id
4. Make sure the payment amount matches what you charge for items. (Defeat Price-Jacking) */

// Check Number 1 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
if ($receiver_email != "chris@test.com") {
    $message = "Investigate why and how receiver email is wrong. Email = " . $_POST['receiver_email'] . "\n\n\n$req";
    mail("chris@test.com", "Receiver Email is incorrect", $message, "From: chris@test.com" );
    exit(); // exit script
}
// Check number 2 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if ($_POST['payment_status'] != "Completed") {
    // Handle how you think you should if a payment is not complete yet, a few scenarios can cause a transaction to be incomplete
}
// Connect to database ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
require_once 'db_conx.php';
// Check number 3 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
$this_txn = $_POST['txn_id'];
$sql = "SELECT id FROM transactions WHERE txn_id='$this_txn' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$numRows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
//
if ($numRows > 0) {
    $message = "Duplicate transaction ID occured so we killed the IPN script. \n\n\n$req";
    mail("chris@test.com", "Duplicate txn_id in the IPN system", $message, "From: chris@test.com" );
    exit(); // exit script
} 
// Check number 4 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$product_id_string = $_POST['custom'];
$product_id_string = rtrim($product_id_string, ","); // remove last comma
// Explode the string, make it an array, then query all the prices out, add them up, and make sure they match the payment_gross amount
$id_str_array = explode(",", $product_id_string); // Uses Comma(,) as delimiter(break point)
$fullAmount = 0;
foreach ($id_str_array as $key => $value) {

    $id_quantity_pair = explode("-", $value); // Uses Hyphen(-) as delimiter to separate product ID from its quantity
    $product_id = $id_quantity_pair[0]; // Get the product ID
    $product_quantity = $id_quantity_pair[1]; // Get the quantity 
    $sqlCommand = "SELECT price FROM products WHERE id='$product_id' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sqlCommand);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $product_price = $row["price"];
    }
    $product_price = $product_price * $product_quantity;
    $fullAmount = $fullAmount + $product_price;
}
$fullAmount = number_format($fullAmount, 2);
$grossAmount = $_POST['mc_gross']; 
if ($fullAmount != $grossAmount) {
        $message = "Possible Price Jack: " . $_POST['payment_gross'] . " != $fullAmount \n\n\n$req";
        mail("chris@test.com", "Price Jack or Bad Programming", $message, "From: chris@test.com" );
        exit(); // exit script
} 

//
//



// END ALL SECURITY CHECKS NOW IN THE DATABASE IT GOES ------------------------------------
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Homework - Examples of assigning local variables from the POST variables
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$custom = $_POST['custom'];
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$payment_date = $_POST['payment_date'];
$mc_gross = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['payment_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$payment_type = $_POST['payment_type'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$txn_type = $_POST['txn_type'];
$payer_status = $_POST['payer_status'];
$address_street = $_POST['address_street'];
$address_city = $_POST['address_city'];
$address_state = $_POST['address_state'];
$address_zip = $_POST['address_zip'];
$address_country = $_POST['address_country'];
$address_status = $_POST['address_status'];
$notify_version = $_POST['notify_version'];
$verify_sign = $_POST['verify_sign'];
$payer_id = $_POST['payer_id'];
$mc_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$mc_fee = $_POST['mc_fee'];

 //
require_once 'db_conx.php';

//$username .= substr($email, 0, strpos($email, '@'));
$user_name = $_POST['first_name'];
// Place the transaction into the database   
   $sql = "INSERT INTO transactions (product_id_array, email, first_name, last_name, payment_date, mc_gross, payment_currency, txn_id, receiver_email, payment_type, payment_status, txn_type, payer_status, address_street, address_city, address_state, address_zip, address_country, address_status, notify_version, verify_sign, payer_id, mc_currency, mc_fee, ip, username)       
       VALUES('$custom','$payer_email','$first_name','$last_name','$payment_date','$mc_gross','$payment_currency','$txn_id','$receiver_email','$payment_type','$payment_status','$txn_type','$payer_status','$address_street','$address_city','$address_state','$address_zip','$address_country','$address_status','$notify_version','$verify_sign','$payer_id','$mc_currency','$mc_fee','$ip','$user_name')";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);//or die (mysqli_error($myConnection)) add this before ; for error checking
$to      = $payer_email;  
$subject = '| Login Credentials';  
$message = ' 

Your officially all ready to go. To login use the information below.

Your account login information 
------------------------- 
Email: '.$payer_email.' 
Password: '.$password.' 
------------------------- 

You can now login at https://www.test.com/signin.php';  
$headers = 'From:noreply@test.com' . "\r\n";  

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);  
// Mail yourself the details
mail("chris@test.com", "NORMAL IPN RESULT YAY MONEY!", $req, "From: chris@test.com");

?>
```

Comment: You can add a txt log in your script, to be written with all the messages you want

Comment: Add calls tp PHP's [error_log()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) function to write data to the system logger, or a file, or to email.

Comment: @RobertRozas I've tried 

`ini_set('log_errors', true);
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__).'/ipn_errors.log');`

I didn't get anything within my ipn_errors.log file

Comment: You can modify your php code and include a manual log....show me your php code to make an example of your php code with a manual log.

Comment: I've attached my entire IPN script to the original post

Answer (score 0):

the ipn listener is triggered by an arbitrary transaction sobeit incomplete, invalid etc. in the ipn listener itself you can specify what should be handled whether it be error logging or even mailing the error to a specified email address. I have implemented the ipn handler to update database values on a valid transaction